# Writing an "if" condition for an even number in a specific range

Tags: java, if-statement

If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5 , print Not Weird

```
if((n%2==0) && (n>=2&&n=>5)){
        System.out.println("Not Wierd");}
```

This is how i wrote it, idk what mistake i did, can someone help me please?!

**The whole program**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRank {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      int n = scan.nextInt(); 
      scan.close();
      String ans="";

      // if 'n' is NOT evenly divisible by 2 (i.e.: n is odd)
      if(n%2==1){
         ans = "Wierd";
      }
      else if((n%2==0) && (n>=2&&n=>5)){
          ans = "Not Wierd";
      }
        System.out.print(ans);
    }

    }
```

Comment: `if((n%2==0) && (n>=2&&n<=5)){`

Comment: `n%2 == 0 && n>=2 && n <=5`

Comment: You probably need to find a good beginners book or tutorial. What you're asking about is pretty basic.

Comment: in the future when you need to find the error in your existing code. Please specify the expected and current behaviour.

Comment: Please read [mcve] for future questions.

Answer (score 1):

The only two numbers that satisfy your condition are `2` and `4`, so you can enumerate them, rather than stating the original condition.

Since the answer for special case can be constructed from the answer for the general case by adding a prefix, the entire code can be expressed in a single line:

```
System.out.print(((n == 2 || n == 4) ? "Not " : "") + "Weird");
```

Answer (score 0):

`=>` is not a valid operator. This should be `n<=5`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n>=2 && n<=5 && n%2==0){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake at the line `else if((n%2==0) && (n>=2&&n=>5)){`. You should have checked for `n<=5` on the last condition.

Please use the below code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestRank {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();
        String ans = "";

        // if 'n' is NOT evenly divisible by 2 (i.e.: n is odd)
        if (n % 2 == 1) {
            ans = "Wierd";
        } else if (n % 2 == 0 && n >= 2 && n <= 5) {
            ans = "Not Wierd";
        }
        System.out.print(ans);
    }

}
```